# Boxplot no padrão do R

Tags: r

Pretendo ligar uma linha conectando diversos boxplots no `R`. Já tentei utilizar as funções `abline` e `lines`, mas não obtive sucesso. Como posso resolver meu problema?

Comment: Coloque o código e um exemplo, isso vai facilitar a resposta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como não foram fornecidos dados para resolver o problema, utilizarei o conjunto de dados `iris` para resolvê-lo. Este conjunto de dados possui 150 observações em 4 variáveis quantitativas e 1 categórica. Esta variável categórica possui três níveis. Por causa destas características, este conjunto de dados se torna bem interessante para ilustrar como resolver este problema.

Além disso, resolverei ele de dois modos: com a função `boxplot`, que é padrão do `R`, e com o pacote `ggplot2`.

### Boxplot Padrão

Em primeiro lugar precisamos plotar o boxplot simples, utilizando uma variável quantitativa como resposta e uma variável categórica como preditora:

```
boxplot(Petal.Length ~ Species, data=iris)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A seguir, é necessário calcular a mediana para cada espécie de planta, que modo que os boxplots sejam conectados de acordo a algum critério. Uma maneira de fazer isto é com a função aggregate:

```
aggregate(iris$Petal.Length, list(iris$Species), median)
     Group.1    x
1     setosa 1.50
2 versicolor 4.35
3  virginica 5.55
```

Para que o gráfico saia mais facilmente, vou salvar este resultado dentro de um objeto chamado `medianas`. A partir disso, basta usar `lines` e plotar as medianas calculadas em cima do boxplot gerado, considerando que cada nível da variável `Species` pode ser entendido como um número de 1 a 3:

```
medianas <- aggregate(iris$Petal.Length, list(iris$Species), median)
lines(1:3, medianas$x)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Boxplot com `ggplot2`

Acho esta solução mais elegante, pois o próprio `ggplot2` calcula e plota sozinho as estatísticas que desejamos colocar no gráfico. Para isto, basta utilizar a função `stat_summary`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", lwd=1, aes(group=1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]